# Run Jasmine tests inside LockerService

Tags: unit-test, javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

I am trying to run our JavaScript tests (written with [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/)) inside  LockerService. I know Salesforce did the same with jQuery in the past because they mentioned it during the last Dreamforce event.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Anyway I could use the Aura framework Github project and hook it to my CI?

Comment: Which sessions in particular are you referring to? Can you link to them? Several of them touched on Jasmine.

Comment: Bob Buzzard gave a talk about running Unit tests using Jasmine. He mentioned that he had to do some changes in the Jasmine source as it is not strictly lockerservice compliant.

Comment: Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gh-FtOIsejA&t=1382s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a POC for using jasmine for component level functional tests at,
https://github.com/esalman-sfdc/lighning-test-service-poc

*Safe Harbor*: 
We (salesforce) are planning to showcase a more elaborate locker service compliant version of this soon via an official repo (e.g. a repo under github.com/forcedotcom) with more examples soon.

I can update this thread once that happens if you are interested.

Comment: Pilot program for Lightning Test Service is now open. Repo hosting documentation and samples for the pilot is at https://github.com/forcedotcom/LightningTestingService

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below github package.this demonstrates how jasmine can be used to test with lightning components. This has been presented in dreamforce as well.

https://github.com/keirbowden/LtgJasmineUnitTesting

Youtube link:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gh-FtOIsejA
```